# facing problems with launch file

Tags: ros, urdf, roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner, I am trying to launch a URDF file in rviz with the following code :

launch file code :

```
<launch>

<arg name="model" />


<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find robot_description)/urdf/final_arm.urdf" />

<param name="use_gui" value="true"/>

<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />

<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />

<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find robot_description)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />

</launch>
```

---

urdf file code (final_arm.urdf) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="ARM">

<link name="base_link">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robot_description/meshes/base_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
</link>


     <joint name="base_joint" type="revolute">
       <parent link="base_link"/>
       <child link="shoulder_link"/>
       <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
       <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
       <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14"/>
       <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
     </joint>

<link name="shoulder_link">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robot_description/meshes/shoulder_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0"izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
</link>


<joint name="shoulder_joint" type="revolute">
       <parent link="shoulder_link"/>
       <child link="elbo_link"/>
       <origin xyz="-0.385379 0.00451305 0.398126"/>
       <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
       <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14"/>
       <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
     </joint>


<link name="elbo_link">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robot_description/meshes/elbo_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0"izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
</link>


<joint name="elbo_joint" type="revolute">
       <parent link="elbo_link"/>
       <child link="wrist_link"/>
       <origin xyz="-0.692963 0.022576 0.569845"/>
       <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
       <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14"/>
       <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
     </joint>



<link name="wrist_link">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robot_description/meshes/wrist_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0"izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
</link>

<joint name="wrist_joint" type="revolute">
       <parent link="wrist_link"/>
       <child link="wrist2_link"/>
       <origin xyz="-0.580553 -0.720985 0.109695"/>
       <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
       <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14"/>
       <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
  </joint>


<link name="wrist2_link">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robot_description/meshes/wrist2_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0"izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
</link>

<joint name="wrist2_joint" type="revolute">
       <parent link="wrist2_link"/>
       <child link="wrist3_link"/>
       <origin xyz="0.483333 0 0.55"/>
       <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
       <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14"/>
       <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
  </joint>

<link name="wrist3_link">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robot_description/meshes/wrist3_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0"izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
</link>

<joint name="wrist3_joint" type="revolute">
       <parent link="wrist3_link"/>
       <child link="wrist4_link"/>
       <origin xyz="0.343334 0.55 0"/>
       <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
       <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14"/>
       <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
  </joint>


<link name="wrist4_link">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robot_description/meshes/wrist4_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0"izz="1.0"/>
      </inertial>
</link>


</robot>
```

---

package name is robot_description, I facing the problem :
when I tried to launch the file with : roslauch robot_description final_arm.launch I get the following error :

```
[final_arm.launch] is neither a launch file in package [robot_description] nor is [robot_description] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

what should I do to solve this, please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286474/facing-problems-with-launch-file/) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-25**:
What is the output of `rospack find robot_description`?

**Comment by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on 2018-03-25**:
output :
/home/profx/catkin_ws/src/robot_description_pkg

**Comment by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on 2018-03-25**:
the real problem is Rviz is not able to find tf for any of the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to be specific with the name of your package. The launch file, urdf and command all specify `robot_description`, but it looks like your package's folder is called `robot_description_pkg`. You need to use one or the other, but not both.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0